# Cassandra. Why cant materialized views have secondary indexes?

Tags: cassandra

Why cannot materialized views(MV) in Cassandra have secondary indexes? Logically all tables in Cassandra are materialized views .i.e. tables cannot have foreign keys and are modeled based on queries. That is what is a View in RDBMS world.
So all that the Cassandra Materialized Views does is; it automates denormalization. If am going to do manual denormalization and I can have secondary indexes in my 2nd table. Why cannot I have secondary indexes in my table (MV) that got created in an automated way.
I noticed [lot that lot of others](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11144) had requested something similar and I am not convinced why its a bad idea by design.
Is Cassandra MV a true View? It only supports Not Null where clause. So are we confusing and limiting ourselves by naming automated denormalizer as MV.

Note: I know the disadvantages of secondary indexes. I don't use it. I have a peculiar requirement where in I need a SASI secondary index to do a LIKE query. New feature part of Cassandra 3.4+. I prefer combining my secondary index need with the pros of MV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for your question is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11144

Long story short, the reason is that having 2nd index on views can limit future change of implementation of views (some people are thinking about using RAMP transaction in a probable future to enforce atomicity of update for views for example)

Comment: Is Cassandra MV a true View? It only supports Not Null where clause. So are we confusing and limiting ourselves by naming automated denormalizer as MV.

Comment: These NOT NULL clauses are there to avoid null values for primary keys. And currently there are some limitations with MV, read my blog post here: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930